# How to record footage from AcroBee Lite?

Tags: video-recording

I have an [AcroBee Lite](https://newbeedrone.com/products/acrobee-lite-rtf-kit)(linked to the site I bought it) that I've gotten okay with, and now I would like to record some footage with it. The only problem is, I can't figure out how to record. Any idea what buttons I have to push to start/stop recording? Where can I find the files after I record them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just scanned the manual for "record" and nothing. I looked at the build and I see no indication of recording capability.

There are 3 options (unless there is more information):

1. Record on goggle. Some goggles have a DVR built in, generally low quality.
2. Record on a dedicated DVR on device, goggle, or another receiver.  I have used all of these options, DVR's start at $20.
3. Mod it and put in a recording camera (if possible).  This will get you to 1080p fast (if possible).  RunCam, Caddx, and Foxeer all have models. I was working on [this spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LcBnglEGocGGNPuDHN51E_5pfO-N3UaSVPl0sx_mRJ8/edit?usp=sharing) last week for our sub-250 units researching mounting trends - it is not complete but has a lot of the key players.

I know the New Bee guys and they should be able to help you out.